# Is it possible to sort an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, sorting

I have an ArcPy Data Access update cursor that I would like to sort before making updates to it.

The cursor makes updates if I don't sort, but if I add a sort to the cursor I get an error, "iteration not started."

The sort is working correctly but it must be busting the cursor for some reason.

Is it not possible to sort an update cursor like a search cursor? Does it change the type or something?

```
    idList = ['100100', '100200', '100300', '200100']
    count = 0
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(newFC, ("SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "Label")) as addLabelCursor:            
        for row in sorted(addLabelCursor, key=itemgetter(0), reverse = True): 
            print idList[count]
            row[2] = str(idList[count])
            addLabelCursor.updateRow(row)
            count += 1
```

Comment: If I watch the locals in a debug session the "addLabelCursor" remains a da.UpdateCursor object all the way through. Its not like its getting converted to a list when its sorted.

Comment: It is failing at: addLabelCursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: You need to sort within the cursor call using an sql clause (ORDER BY)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sort completely exhausts the cursor before you go into `updateRow`. The way that cursors work is that the `updateRow` call doesn't work on arbitrary rows out-of-seqence, but on the current one being iterated over. That is, you can only operate on one row at a time.

You may want to look into doing this on the geodatabase side instead. You can specify an `ORDER BY` clause and sort it before you get to it instead.

Comment: It looks like you cannot use the geometry tokens in the sql clause of a cursor. I'll have to use a work around like adding it to a real field before hand or maybe I will just store this cursors input in memory and use a search cursor to sort and insert cursor to create. Thanks for confirming that I cannot sort an update cursor and still update.

Comment: @TurboGus but you *can* sort the rows in a cursor. The [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) indicates you can specify the `sql_clause` (tuple) parameter: `sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY SORT_FIELD ASC')` -- or `DESC` for descending.

Answer (score 2):

As @nmpeterson pointed out, you can input an sql clause into the cursor call to sort by a field:

> UpdateCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause},
> {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, **{sql_clause}**)
>
> SQL prefix supports None, DISTINCT, and TOP. SQL postfix supports None, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY.
>
> sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY SORT_FIELD ASC') -- or DESC

info comes from the ESRI help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000

Answer (score 0):

It may be only relevant for future reference, but according to [ArcGis online help](http://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/arcpy/functions/updatecursor.htm) when using *arcpy.UpdateCursor* instead of *arcpy.da.UpdateCursor* there is an sort option available.

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc,sort_fields="*YOURFIELDNAME*")