# Sorting an UpdateCursor

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, sorting

I'm trying to sort a dataset by field `StartTime` (datatype date, indicates when a technician is supposed to start a visit). I am including a SQL where_clause to avoid an earlier problem when it complained it couldn't compare a date to a NULL value.

```
for Technician in TechList:
    insertFields = ["StartTime", "AssignedTech", "VisitOrder"]
    sql = """"StartTime" IS NOT NULL"""
    print sql
    counter = 1
    with sorted(arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcStops, insertFields, sql)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1] == Technician:
                row[2] = counter
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                counter += 1
```

The problem is in the `sorted` (an idea I got from the [ArcMap SearchCursor help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/#GUID-9FD2DAEE-ADBE-41DF-8AA6-B06EE32619A8), Example 5). If I take that out, it runs but of course is all out of order.

**How can I sort the UpdateCursor so that I'm assigning `VisitOrder` the correct ordered value** -- or is there another way ensure that the first visit gets 1, second 2, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I used is to sort an old-fashioned `UpdateCursor`, since a `da.UpdateCursor` [cannot be sorted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31171/is-it-possible-to-sort-an-arcpy-da-updatecursor).

```
sql = """"StartTime" IS NOT NULL"""
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fcStops, sql, "", "", "StartTime")
for row in rows:
    if row.getValue("AssignedTech") == Technician:
        row.setValue("VisitOrder", counter)
        rows.updateRow(row)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: You could use the `sql_clause` tuple parameter when specifying your `da.UpdateCursor` as follows: `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcStops, insertFields, sql, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY StartTime ASC'))`

Comment: @nmpeterson & Erica - I may have closed this as a Duplicate prematurely (based on Erica's close vote) - do we need to re-open?

Comment: @PolyGeo it is a duplicate, in that both Qs ask the same thing. However, OP of other Q drew incorrect conclusion about sortability of `da` cursors, which misled Erica here. If reopened, I would turn my comment into an answer -- or should I answer the other Q instead?

Comment: I think answering earlier question may be best way forward - thanks!

Comment: @nmpeterson THANK YOU, I couldn't figure out how to use `ORDER BY` within Arc's syntax!  I agree that answering the other question is best though :D